# Automatically fetch component,result file name in the mos script

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

Using a mos script, I am reading and plotting the data of certain variables that belong to a component 'x' in my model. If the component name is changed from 'x' to 'y', how can it be updated automatically in the script? I would like to write a flexible script so that it can be used even though the name of the result file or component is changed.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you share a script snippet to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve? Maybe you could use getInstanceName() maybe? https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/getInstanceName.html

Comment: @matth simulateModel("PID_Controller", stopTime=4, resultFile="PID_Controller");
createPlot(id=1, y={"kinematicPTP.sdd"},grid=true); Lets assume that I renamed 'kinematicPTP' in the model. So, I want to assign it to some variable and the variable should be updated when  change the name. getInstanceName() doesn't seem to work in script, it gave me this error "Warning: Failed to expand getInstanceName. Must first ensure that resources are added to the directory of the library
Error: Normal function call of function ModelicaInternal_print, but the function is declared with 0 outputs" .

Answer (score 1):

It is (currently) not possible to do this automatically in Dymola.

You might be able to reduce the problem by creating a variable for the expression, `Real mySdd=kinematicPTP.sdd;` and then plot `mySdd`. Renaming `kinematicPTP` will not cause any problems in this case. (Obviously renaming `mySdd` causes the same problems, but the idea would be that those names are more stable.)

Comment: Hi, I tried like you said, but it didn't work. My case is like this. I have a component 'cell' which has variables a,b and c. I now store 'cell' in variable 'name' as you suggested, name=cell; I then use them in the script(x=name.a; y=name.b). Next,the user renames the component to 'newCell'. The variable 'name' won't get updated now(coz 'cell' doesn't exist anymore) so my x,y's will not be updated as well. Also, one more question, is it possible to assign the entire component(record variable), in this example 'cell', to a variable or I have to assign individual variables?Thank you

Comment: In Dymola if you rename "cell" using a dialog such as parameter-dialog or variable declaration-dialog then uses of "cell" should be renamed (at least in the current model, for other models you might have to enable that feature). It should also work for records - but there is a point when everything is just duplicated without any benefit.